Why does my laundry supply hose extension coupler leak?
I replaced a washing machine and decided to replace the previous supply lines (brass ends, they were rusty and the mesh inside the lines had a lot of build up). The washing machine and lines were about 15 years old.
I went ahead and bought stainless steel supply lines. One issue was that the hot and cold is about 9 FT away from the actual unit, so I bought two packs of supply lines. There were existing brass fittings to extend the hoses by hooking them up together so I re-used those.
I have a few questions:

I heard straight threads that utilize a rubber washer don't need teflon tape (NPS?). I ended up adding some because one of the connections kept dripping ever so slightly on me.

One of the connectors didn't seem to thread all the way. I'm not sure why - I inspected the threads and they looked fine. I had to add a second washer in the supply line end to get it to stop leaking.

I don't know what the consensus is with regards to mixing brass and stainless?


I think ideally I would extend the plumbing to only use one pair of these hoses so I don't have to use those brass fittings, but I was still curious about why I would get drips. I hand tightened and did a 3/4 turn with a vice grip (the supply line terminations don't seem to be designed to be tightened much since they are basically round with some notches).


It could be possible that you don't have the correct brass connectors for back to back female hose ends. The visible adapter threads look to me like they're not garden hose threads:

source
Garden hose threads are not tapered like pipe threads. They are straight and will grip properly at any point along the thread path, as long as there's a couple threads in the fixture and the end of the threads seats firmly on the rubber washer.
Garden hose threads do not need teflon tape. They depend on the rubber washer to seal between the end of the male part and the flat-flared top of the female part. The threads themselves only hold the pressure against the rubber washer. The threads do not provide any water blocking.
I have also extended washing machine hoses with male/male garden hose adapters.
If the brass connectors you have actually are not garden hose adapters, then you need new washing machine hoses: those connectors are ruined from the non-garden-hose threads of the adapter.
Try either finding longer washing machine hoses or get proper male/male adapters and new short hoses. (FWIW I found 12 foot washing machine hoses at the orange big box store.)

I disagree that the hoses are ruined. Since those threads don't seal anything they're probably fine (if a little gritty). I would try them first before wasting them.

You have a point there, @isherwood the hoses may still work. I'd be leery myself, since there's constant water pressure in them, and if it would fail, it'd fail when I'm not home, for sure... :D

There's really no way they'd fail. Either you could thread them on or you couldn't. If they're on, they're not coming off.

Often those brass couplers are designed to seal with olives on copper pipe so the ends are not flattened sufficiently to work with the washers.
This seems to be confirmed by you when you mention fitting 2 washers.
A "quick" solution would be to get the coupler faces machined to provide the washers with flat mating surfaces but I would be going the other route and extending the plumbing.
Do keep a check on the end with the double washer as that means less thread is engaged and it could fail with the pressure pulses as the valves are opened and closed.
Edit based on comment:
Olives (not green or black) but in brass, and sometimes copper, are used to make the seal between the pipe and the coupler.
See
 from https://www.screwfix.com/p/flomasta-brass-compression-olives-22mm-20-pack/51520

@isherwood definitely an industry term, used by professionals in the plumbing industry and many other industries where that type of connection is used. See my edit for a picture of an olive - not edible unless your middle name is Marvin ( the paranoid android) from HHG.

Web-searching "Plumbing olive" returns Solar Mike's description. FWIW industry calls things differently in different areas. In my location, cabinet shops call the good-looking add-on panel on the end of a cabinet an "applied finished end". In some places in Canada it's called a "plant-on gable". Go figure...

@isherwood if you read the link I supplied to go with the image it even contains the word "olive", and if you search that site you will easily find them win sizes of 8mm, 10mm, 15mm, 22mm, 28mm and more...

@isherwood By googling it, it might well be UK-AUS. And so what? Does he have to look up every single term to make sure what it's called anywhere across the globe? Besides, what makes one regional buzzword any better than another regional buzzword? He even provided an image, so you can understand and mentally replace with another word if you happen to use a different word for it. Sheesh...

TIL that this is called a "biconical ring" or "olive" in French. I guess people will use "olive" :)

And in Dutch, it's a "knelring", which essentially means "squeeze ring", or "compressiering" ("compression ring") if you're feeling fancy.
Jargon can be very local, so being descriptive, whether by means of picking a descriptive term, or by explaining the jargon, can be quite helpful.
In this case, if you add the right context, google will certainly get you an answer, but that's not always the case (or the right search terms can be hard to find, for more esoteric jargon), and "olive" is hardly a descriptive word.

9 feet - it is around 3 meters. Max avaible universals are up to 5m, dishwasher/washing machine ones are up to 15m.
Buy right lenght ones and replace this. Less points of failure is (in most cases) beter.

Nice and pungent: Get the right length hose. +1!
